# How to make an image move using OOP

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame, and I'm trying to get the image (Player1) to move in OOP. I initially used procedural and it worked but when I put it into OOP format, the image no longer works.

This is the code I used when doing procedural programming, which I got by adapting code I found from https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#comment_pygame_key_name

```
#Moving player
import pygame
pygame.init()

ScreenSize = 1200, 600
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode(ScreenSize)
Screen.fill([255, 255, 255])

XPos = 0
YPos = 0
Plyr = []
PlyrRct = []

Background = pygame.image.load('carpet.jpg')
Player = pygame.image.load('player.jpg')

PlayerTemp = Player.subsurface(1, 0, 64, 64)
PlayerRectTemp = PlayerTemp.get_rect()
Plyr.append(PlayerTemp)
PlyrRct.append(PlayerRectTemp)

End = False
while not End:
    Key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if Key[pygame.K_a]:
        XPos -= 4
    if Key[pygame.K_d]:
        XPos += 4
    if Key[pygame.K_w]:
        YPos -= 4
    if Key[pygame.K_s]:
        YPos += 4

    Background = pygame.image.load('carpet.jpg')
    Screen.blit(Background, (0, 0))

    PlyrRct[0].left = XPos
    PlyrRct[0].top = YPos
    Screen.blit(Plyr[0], PlyrRct[0])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is currently my oop program

```
# Player Move test

import pygame
pygame.init()

class LoadImages(object):

    def __init__(self, Image, Top, Left, Width, Height):
        self.Image = pygame.image.load(Image)
        self.Top = Top
        self.Bottom = Top + Height
        self.Left = Left
        self.Right = Left + Width

class Player(LoadImages):

    def __init__(self, Image, Top, Left, Width, Height):
        LoadImages.__init__(self, Image, Top, Left, Width, Height)

    def Move(self, A, D, W, S):
        #self.CheckCollision()
        if A:
            self.Left -= 4
            self.Right -= 4
        if D:
            self.Left += 4
            self.Right += 4
        if W:
            self.Top += 4
            self.Bottom += 4
        if S:
            self.Top -= 4
            self.Bottom -= 4

    #def CheckCollision(self):
        #print ()

class Item(LoadImages):

    def __init__(self, Image, Top, Left, Width, Height):
        LoadImages.__init__(self, Image, Top, Left, Width, Height)

    #def Examine(self):
        #print ()

Player1 = Player("player.jpg", 0, 0, 300, 300)
Item1 = Item("player.jpg", 0, 0, 300, 300)
Background = pygame.image.load("carpet.jpg")

ScreenSize = 1200, 600
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode(ScreenSize)
Screen.fill([255, 255, 255])

End = False
while not End:
    Screen.blit(Background, (0, 0))
    Screen.blit(Player1.Image, (Player1.Top, Player1.Left))
    pygame.display.update()

    Key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    Player1.Move(Key[pygame.K_a], Key[pygame.K_d], Key[pygame.K_w], Key[pygame.K_s])
```

I'm expecting the image (Player1) to move on the screen but it won't move anywhere.
The images in the program are just being used for testing purposes and will be replaced with a .png

Comment: If all of your code is here, nothing can happen: you didn't instantiate your classes, nor did you call any method.

Comment: I've instantiated them under the item class, and called the method in the while loop. The images appear, they just don't move. Sorry if I misunderstood your comment

Comment: Rethink your `OOP` layout using **only** these three `class objects`: **1.** `class Figure:`, **2.** `class Player(Figure)`, **3.** `class Game():`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the event processing in your second example. If you don't call `pygame.event.get()` (or `poll()`), your window won't respond (depending on your OS/window manager).

So simple add

```
for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
        End = True
```

to your `while` loop.

Also, since you're using pygame, take a look at its Sprite class, which you can use for OOP with pygame. Somewhat related to your question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988851/running-a-if-statement-only-once-in-pygame/54004065#54004065). Maybe you'll find it useful.