# Is there an effiecient way of making a function to drag and drop multiple png's?

Tags: python, pygame, chess

I'm making a chess game, but I'm completely stuck on the drag and drop element, there's a few guides out there but they're all either dragging shapes, or only dragging one image.

I've tried several variants of code, but all were 50+ lines just to move one `.png` and most were incredibly inefficient

```py
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Python Chess")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
red = (213,43,67)
chew = pygame.image.load("chew.png")

gameDisplay.fill(red)
gameDisplay.blit(chew, (400, 400))
pygame.display.update()

drag = 0
if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    drag = 1
if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    drag = 0

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
```

Image simply doesn't drag.

Comment: Well, dragging images will be generally slow because it's redrawing each sequence. If you buffer your draw with small moves (e.g. by 1 pixel), it's gonna be slowly following your mouse. What you need is move at current mouse position (+-correction for where you grabbed the image).

Comment: For multiple images, it will be the same - just store somewhere what images are selected (decide how to select them first and implement it and deselection) and then move them like a single image (remember: to the current mouse position +- offset, not by one pixel each time in the mouse's direction).

Comment: [I haven't worked with pygame, so my comments are general, about how it works generally in image rendering and handling mouse events - but I've done that in 2 compiled languages, not interpreted Python, so please correct me if something's different in Python.]

Comment: you have to compare `if even.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: drag = 1`  inside `while` loop.

Comment: `PyGame` is low-level library, not game engine, so it needs 50+ lines to make even something simple.

Comment: Also, less lines of code does not mean more effiecient. I guess instead of 'effiecient', you're looking for 'simple' and 'easy-to-understand'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's walk through this step by step.

## Step 1: Let's start with a basic skeleton of every pygame game:

```
import pygame

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

We create a window and then start a loop to listen for events and drawing the window.

[image]

So far, so good. Nothing to see here, let's move on.

---

## Step 2: a chess board

So, we want a chess game. So we need a board. We create a list of lists to represent our board, and we create a `Surface` that draws our board on the screen. We want to always seperate our game's state from the actual drawing functions, so we create a `board` variable and a `board_surf`.

```
import pygame

TILESIZE = 32

def create_board_surf():
    board_surf = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE*8, TILESIZE*8))
    dark = False
    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*TILESIZE, y*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(board_surf, pygame.Color('black' if dark else 'white'), rect)
            dark = not dark
        dark = not dark
    return board_surf

def create_board():
    board = []
    for y in range(8):
        board.append([])
        for x in range(8):
            board[y].append(None)
    return board

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    board = create_board()
    board_surf = create_board_surf()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        screen.blit(board_surf, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

---

## Step 3: Where's the mouse?

We need to know which piece we want to select, so we have to translate the **screen coordinates** (*where's the mouse relative to the window?*) to the **world coordinates** (*which square of the board is the mouse pointing to?*).

So if the board is not located at the *origin* (the position `(0, 0)`), we also have to take this *offset* into account.

Basically, we have to substract that *offset* (which is the position of the board on the screen) from the mouse position (so we have the mouse position relative to the board), and divide by the size of the squares.

To see if this works, let's draw a red rectangle on the selected square.

```
import pygame

TILESIZE = 32
BOARD_POS = (10, 10)

def create_board_surf():
    board_surf = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE*8, TILESIZE*8))
    dark = False
    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*TILESIZE, y*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(board_surf, pygame.Color('black' if dark else 'white'), rect)
            dark = not dark
        dark = not dark
    return board_surf

def create_board():
    board = []
    for y in range(8):
        board.append([])
        for x in range(8):
            board[y].append(None)
    return board

def get_square_under_mouse(board):
    mouse_pos = pygame.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) - BOARD_POS
    x, y = [int(v // TILESIZE) for v in mouse_pos]
    try: 
        if x >= 0 and y >= 0: return (board[y][x], x, y)
    except IndexError: pass
    return None, None, None

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    board = create_board()
    board_surf = create_board_surf()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        piece, x, y = get_square_under_mouse(board)

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        screen.blit(board_surf, BOARD_POS)

        if x != None:
            rect = (BOARD_POS[0] + x * TILESIZE, BOARD_POS[1] + y * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0, 50), rect, 2)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

---

## Step 4: Let's draw some pieces

Chess is boring without some pieces to move around, so let's create some pieces.

I just use a `SysFont` to draw some text instead of using real images, so everyone can just copy/paste the code and run it immediately.

We store a tuple `(color, type)` in the nested `board` list. Also, let's use some other colors for our board.

```
import pygame

TILESIZE = 32
BOARD_POS = (10, 10)

def create_board_surf():
    board_surf = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE*8, TILESIZE*8))
    dark = False
    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*TILESIZE, y*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(board_surf, pygame.Color('darkgrey' if dark else 'beige'), rect)
            dark = not dark
        dark = not dark
    return board_surf

def get_square_under_mouse(board):
    mouse_pos = pygame.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) - BOARD_POS
    x, y = [int(v // TILESIZE) for v in mouse_pos]
    try: 
        if x >= 0 and y >= 0: return (board[y][x], x, y)
    except IndexError: pass
    return None, None, None

def create_board():
    board = []
    for y in range(8):
        board.append([])
        for x in range(8):
            board[y].append(None)

    for x in range(0, 8):
        board[1][x] = ('black', 'pawn')
    for x in range(0, 8):
        board[6][x] = ('white', 'pawn') 

    return board

def draw_pieces(screen, board, font):
    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8): 
            piece = board[y][x]
            if piece:
                color, type = piece
                s1 = font.render(type[0], True, pygame.Color(color))
                s2 = font.render(type[0], True, pygame.Color('darkgrey'))
                pos = pygame.Rect(BOARD_POS[0] + x * TILESIZE+1, BOARD_POS[1] + y * TILESIZE + 1, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
                screen.blit(s2, s2.get_rect(center=pos.center).move(1, 1))
                screen.blit(s1, s1.get_rect(center=pos.center))

def draw_selector(screen, piece, x, y):
    if piece != None:
        rect = (BOARD_POS[0] + x * TILESIZE, BOARD_POS[1] + y * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0, 50), rect, 2)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('', 32)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    board = create_board()
    board_surf = create_board_surf()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        piece, x, y = get_square_under_mouse(board)

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        screen.blit(board_surf, BOARD_POS)
        draw_pieces(screen, board, font)
        draw_selector(screen, piece, x, y)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

---

## Step 5: Drag'n'Drop

For drag and drop we need two things:

- we have to change the state of your game (going into the "drag-mode")
- eventhandling to enter and leave the "drag-mode"

It's actually not that complicated. To enter the "drag-mode", we just set a variable (`selected_piece`) when the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs. Since we already have the `get_square_under_mouse` function, it's easy to know if there's actually a piece under the mouse cursor.

if `selected_piece` is set, we draw a line and the piece under the mouse cursor, and we keep track of the current square under the cursor in case the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs. If that's the case, we swap the position of the piece in our `board`.

```
import pygame

TILESIZE = 32
BOARD_POS = (10, 10)

def create_board_surf():
    board_surf = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE*8, TILESIZE*8))
    dark = False
    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*TILESIZE, y*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(board_surf, pygame.Color('darkgrey' if dark else 'beige'), rect)
            dark = not dark
        dark = not dark
    return board_surf

def get_square_under_mouse(board):
    mouse_pos = pygame.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) - BOARD_POS
    x, y = [int(v // TILESIZE) for v in mouse_pos]
    try: 
        if x >= 0 and y >= 0: return (board[y][x], x, y)
    except IndexError: pass
    return None, None, None

def create_board():
    board = []
    for y in range(8):
        board.append([])
        for x in range(8):
            board[y].append(None)

    for x in range(0, 8):
        board[1][x] = ('black', 'pawn')
    for x in range(0, 8):
        board[6][x] = ('white', 'pawn') 

    return board

def draw_pieces(screen, board, font, selected_piece):
    sx, sy = None, None
    if selected_piece:
        piece, sx, sy = selected_piece

    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8): 
            piece = board[y][x]
            if piece:
                selected = x == sx and y == sy
                color, type = piece
                s1 = font.render(type[0], True, pygame.Color('red' if selected else color))
                s2 = font.render(type[0], True, pygame.Color('darkgrey'))
                pos = pygame.Rect(BOARD_POS[0] + x * TILESIZE+1, BOARD_POS[1] + y * TILESIZE + 1, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
                screen.blit(s2, s2.get_rect(center=pos.center).move(1, 1))
                screen.blit(s1, s1.get_rect(center=pos.center))

def draw_selector(screen, piece, x, y):
    if piece != None:
        rect = (BOARD_POS[0] + x * TILESIZE, BOARD_POS[1] + y * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0, 50), rect, 2)

def draw_drag(screen, board, selected_piece, font):
    if selected_piece:
        piece, x, y = get_square_under_mouse(board)
        if x != None:
            rect = (BOARD_POS[0] + x * TILESIZE, BOARD_POS[1] + y * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0, 50), rect, 2)

        color, type = selected_piece[0]
        s1 = font.render(type[0], True, pygame.Color(color))
        s2 = font.render(type[0], True, pygame.Color('darkgrey'))
        pos = pygame.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        screen.blit(s2, s2.get_rect(center=pos + (1, 1)))
        screen.blit(s1, s1.get_rect(center=pos))
        selected_rect = pygame.Rect(BOARD_POS[0] + selected_piece[1] * TILESIZE, BOARD_POS[1] + selected_piece[2] * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color('red'), selected_rect.center, pos)
        return (x, y)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('', 32)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    board = create_board()
    board_surf = create_board_surf()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    selected_piece = None
    drop_pos = None
    while True:
        piece, x, y = get_square_under_mouse(board)
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if piece != None:
                    selected_piece = piece, x, y
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if drop_pos:
                    piece, old_x, old_y = selected_piece
                    board[old_y][old_x] = 0
                    new_x, new_y = drop_pos
                    board[new_y][new_x] = piece
                selected_piece = None
                drop_pos = None

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        screen.blit(board_surf, BOARD_POS)
        draw_pieces(screen, board, font, selected_piece)
        draw_selector(screen, piece, x, y)
        drop_pos = draw_drag(screen, board, selected_piece, font)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Of course there's a lot that can be improved (like using better datatypes than tuples, extract common logic into functions etc), but this should give you a good start on how to implement such things.

Always keep in mind:

- write a single game loop that handles events, game logic, and drawing
- make sure to only call `pygame.display.flip` once per frame
- seperate your game state from your drawing functions
- never call `time.sleep` or `pygame.time.wait`
- use the build-in classes like `Vector2` and `Rect`, they'll make your live easier (I didn't the `Sprite` class in this code, but it's also very usefull)
- use functions to clean up your code
- avoid global variables, except for constants

Comment: Hey sloth, was looking back on this and wanted to incorporate images instead of letters for pieces, and I'm confused on the difference between images and rects, any chance you could help?

Comment: A rect is just a, well a rect, with a position (x, y) and size (width, height). When talking about an image, let's say an image is an image file on your computer, and to do something with it with pygame, you have to create a Surface from that image. Usually you use something like pygame.image.load() to load it from disk. Note that when you use font.render(), like I do in my example above, the result of that function is also a Surface. You can then blit Surface onto other Surfaces, copy them, fill them with color, resize them etc. Usually, when working with pygame, you always use a Surface...

Comment: ...together with a Rect. The Surface holds the image, and the Rect holds the position and the size of that image. Pygame overs a neat way to use both of them together: the sprite class. A sprite has an image attribute and a rect attribute, and you alter the rect to change the sprites position etc. and pygame can handle the drawing and updating the sprite for you via the group class.

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988851/running-a-if-statement-only-once-in-pygame

Comment: So as a first step, if you look at the draw_pieces function above, you can see the s1 and s2 variabels. Instead of using font.render to create them, you would probably load an image from your drive and use that surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

`PyGame` is low-level library, not game engine, and you have to make almost all from scratch.

This example drags two images but for more images it could use list or `pygame.sprite.Group` with `pygame.sprite.Sprites` and then code is getting longer and longer but as I said `PyGame` is not game engine like ie. [Godot Engine](https://godotengine.org/) (which uses language similar to Python). Maybe with [Pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/mouse.html) could be easier because you don't have to write `mainloop` from scratch but it still need some work. In PyGame you have to write from scratch even main element - `mainloop`.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

RED = (213, 43, 67)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

chew1 = pygame.image.load("chew.png")
chew1_rect = chew1.get_rect(x=400, y=400)

chew2 = pygame.image.load("chew.png") # use different image
chew2_rect = chew1.get_rect(x=200, y=200)

drag = 0

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_exit = False

while not game_exit:

    # - events -
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            drag = 1
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            drag = 0
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if drag:
                chew1_rect.move_ip(event.rel)
                chew2_rect.move_ip(event.rel)

    # - draws -            
    screen.fill(RED)
    screen.blit(chew1, chew1_rect)
    screen.blit(chew2, chew2_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -
    clock.tick(30)

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:** the same with `Group` and `Sprite` and now you have to only add images to group `items` and rest of the code doesn't need to be changed.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

RED = (213, 43, 67)

# --- classes ---

class Item(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

    def update(self, rel):
        self.rect.move_ip(rel)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

items = pygame.sprite.Group(
    Item("chew.png", 200, 200),
    Item("chew.png", 400, 200), 
    Item("chew.png", 200, 400),
    Item("chew.png", 400, 400),
)

drag = 0

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_exit = False

while not game_exit:

    # - events -
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            drag = 1
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            drag = 0
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if drag:
                items.update(event.rel)

    # - draws -            
    screen.fill(RED)
    items.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -
    clock.tick(30)

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:** this version use Group to move only clicked image(s). If you click in place where two (or more) images are overlapped then it will drag two (or more) images.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

RED = (213, 43, 67)

# --- classes ---

class Item(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

    def update(self, rel):
        self.rect.move_ip(rel)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

items = pygame.sprite.Group(
    Item("chew.png", 150, 50),
    Item("chew.png", 400, 50), 
    Item("chew.png", 150, 300),
    Item("chew.png", 400, 300),
)

dragged = pygame.sprite.Group()

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_exit = False

while not game_exit:

    # - events -
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dragged.add(x for x in items if x.rect.collidepoint(event.pos))          
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            dragged.empty()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            dragged.update(event.rel)

    # - draws -            
    screen.fill(RED)
    items.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -
    clock.tick(30)

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:** similar program in Pyglet - it moves two images with less code.

Pyglet has point `(0,0)` in left bottom corner.

To create red background it has to draw rectangle (QUADS) in OpenGL.

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=800, height=600)

batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
items = [
    pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.resource.image('chew.png'), x=200, y=100, batch=batch),
    pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.resource.image('chew.png'), x=400, y=300, batch=batch),
]

@window.event
def on_draw():
    #window.clear()
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [0,0, 800,0, 800,600, 0,600]), ('c3B', [213,43,67, 213,43,67, 213,43,67, 213,43,67])) #RED = (213, 43, 67)
    batch.draw()

@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    for i in items:
        i.x += dx
        i.y += dy

pyglet.app.run()
```