# How can I move a sprite image in pygame with my mouse?

Tags: pygame

Okay, I was given this project two weeks ago to create a simple chess game with the same rules as you would play in real life, and the project is due in a week. I really need help on how do I move the pawn or any chess piece up a space by using the mouse (not the keyboard).

Comment: Basically, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987691/142637. Feel free to use my code for your project.

Comment: While this is an interesting problem, your question is not a good fit for stackoverflow, as it does not contain any code and is very broad. Generally, a question is a better fit if it asks for a specific problem without being to broad, and if it contains a minimal, runnable example which reproduces of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if you want to make the (lets just take a pawn for this example) move up `y` pixels, you will want your code to be something like this.

```
screen.blit(pawn,(x,y))
```

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        # key goes down? look for that

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                keys[0] = True
```

then later in your code all of this of course in the main game loop

```
     if keys[0]

         y += 10
```

This requires some variables/images such as pawn, keys, and x/y to be defined. Cheers! also always check the docs before posting here.