# creating and placing game pieces on game board using python and pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am just a beginner programmer. I decided to make a board game using pygame. I have created the board using following code:

```
import pygame
import sys


pygame.init()
#define colour
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow= (255,255,0)



#opening window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (200,100,250,250), 2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (150,75,350,300), 2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (100,50,450,350), 2)
#draw lines
#upper line
pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(325,50),(325,100),3)
#lower line
pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(325,350),(325,400),3)
#left line
pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(100,200),(200,200),3)
#right line
pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(450,200),(550,200),3)

#updateing window
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Now, I want to add two game pieces of two different colours say black and red on each corner and at the point of intersection of the lines. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is too broad and will likely be closed, but maybe you'll find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987691/142637) question/answer helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you find yourself repeating lines with blocks of numbers, like your calls to the rectangle function - think about how maybe storing the numbers in some kind of list, tuple or data-structure can *simplify* the code.

For example:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (200,100,250,250), 2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (150,75,350,300), 2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (100,50,450,350), 2)
```

Could become:

```
board_rects = [  ( 200,100,250,250, red ), ( 150,75,350,300, green ), ( 100,50,450,350, red ) ]
for rect in board_rects:
    x_pos, y_pos  = rect[0], rect[1]
    width, height = rect[2], rect[3]
    colour        = rect[4]
    pygame.draw.rect( screen, colour, ( x_pos, y_pos, width, height ), 2 )
```

Which is obviously more code, but it is simpler as there is only one call to draw all the rectangles.  If say, the number of rectangles increases with the difficulty level, it's only a matter of adding another data-tuple to `board-rects`, there is no logic changes.

Similarly for the lines:

```
board_lines = [ ( 325,50,325,100 ), ( 325,350,325,400 ), ( 100,200,200,200 ), ( 450,200,550,200 ) ]
for line in board_lines:
    line_from = ( line[0], line[1] )
    line_to   = ( line[2], line[3] )
    pygame.draw.line( screen, white, line_from, line_to, 3 )
```

Now both the board's rectangles and lines are stored in a data structure.  So it's  possible to iterate over the list performing other tests and operations.
Now we have all the points and lines in data structures, we can just loop over them doing an intersection point test:

```
for line in board_lines:
    for rect in board_rects:
        rect = rect[ 0: -1 ] # trim off the colour
        intersection_points = lineRectIntersectionPoints( line, rect )
        for p in intersection_points:
            pygame.draw.circle( screen, blue, p, 10 )  # Draw a circle at the point
```

[image: board with circles at points]

One way to determine the intersection point of a line and rectangle is to consider the rectangle as a set of 4 lines, and determine the [intersection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) of the given line with each.  Of course if the lines are parallel, they don't intersect (well they do, but *infinitely*), so we have to check for that too. And finally, we don't care if the lines intersect off-screen, this is considered to be not-intersecting as well.

This gives us that nasty-looking intersection function, but it's really just a bunch of simple geometry calculations tied together:

```
def lineRectIntersectionPoints( line, rect ):
    """ Get the list of points where the line and rect
        intersect,  The result may be zero, one or two points.

        BUG: This function fails when the line and the side
             of the rectangle overlap """

    def linesAreParallel( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return True if the given lines (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) and
            (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) are parallel """
        return (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)) == 0)

    def intersectionPoint( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return the point where the lines through (x1,y1)-(x2,y2)
            and (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) cross.  This may not be on-screen  """
        #Use determinant method, as per
        #Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
        Px = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(x3 - x4)) - ((x1-x2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        Py = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(y3 - y4)) - ((y1-y2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        return Px,Py

    ### Begin the intersection tests
    result = []                                 # empty list for result-set
    line_x1, line_y1, line_x2, line_y2 = line   # split into components
    pos_x, pos_y, width, height = rect

    ### Convert the rectangle into 4 lines
    rect_lines = [ ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y ), ( pos_x, pos_y+height, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ),  # top & bottom
                   ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x, pos_y+height ), ( pos_x+width, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ) ] # left & right

    ### intersect each rect-side with the given line
    for r in rect_lines:
        rx1,ry1,rx2,ry2 = r
        if ( not linesAreParallel( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 ) ):    # not parallel
            pX, pY = intersectionPoint( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 )  # so intersecting somewhere
            # Lines intersect, but is it on-screen?
            if ( pX >= 0 and pY >= 0 and pX < WINDOW_WIDTH and pY < WINDOW_HEIGHT ):          # yes! on-screen
                result.append( ( round(pX), round(pY) ) )                                     # keep it
                if ( len( result ) == 2 ):
                    break   # Once we've found 2 intersection points, that's it

    return result
```

And putting it all together:

```
import pygame
import sys

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT= 600

#define colour
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (121,202,255)
yellow= (255,255,0)


def lineRectIntersectionPoints( line, rect ):
    """ Get the list of points where the line and rect
        intersect,  The result may be zero, one or two points.

        BUG: This function fails when the line and the side
             of the rectangle overlap """

    def linesAreParallel( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return True if the given lines (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) and
            (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) are parallel """
        return (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)) == 0)

    def intersectionPoint( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return the point where the lines through (x1,y1)-(x2,y2)
            and (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) cross.  This may not be on-screen  """
        #Use determinant method, as per
        #Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
        Px = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(x3 - x4)) - ((x1-x2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        Py = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(y3 - y4)) - ((y1-y2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        return Px,Py

    ### Begin the intersection tests
    result = []
    line_x1, line_y1, line_x2, line_y2 = line   # split into components
    pos_x, pos_y, width, height = rect

    ### Convert the rectangle into 4 lines
    rect_lines = [ ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y ), ( pos_x, pos_y+height, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ),  # top & bottom
                   ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x, pos_y+height ), ( pos_x+width, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ) ] # left & right

    ### intersect each rect-side with the line
    for r in rect_lines:
        rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 = r
        if ( not linesAreParallel( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 ) ):    # not parallel
            pX, pY = intersectionPoint( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 )  # so intersecting somewhere
            # Lines intersect, but is it on-screen?
            if ( pX >= 0 and pY >= 0 and pX < WINDOW_WIDTH and pY < WINDOW_HEIGHT ):          # yes! on-screen
                result.append( ( round(pX), round(pY) ) )                                     # keep it
                if ( len( result ) == 2 ):
                    break   # Once we've found 2 intersection points, that's it

    return result



#opening window
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

#pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (200,100,250,250), 2)
#pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (150,75,350,300), 2)
#pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (100,50,450,350), 2)
##draw lines
##upper line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(325,50),(325,100),3)
##lower line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(325,350),(325,400),3)
##left line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(100,200),(200,200),3)
##right line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(450,200),(550,200),3)

board_rects = [  ( 200,100,250,250, red ), ( 150,75,350,300, green ), ( 100,50,450,350, red ) ]
for rect in board_rects:
    x_pos, y_pos  = rect[0], rect[1]
    width, height = rect[2], rect[3]
    colour        = rect[4]
    pygame.draw.rect( screen, colour, ( x_pos, y_pos, width, height ), 2 )

board_lines = [ ( 325,50,325,100 ), ( 325,350,325,400 ), ( 100,200,200,200 ), ( 450,200,550,200 ) ]
for line in board_lines:
    line_from = ( line[0], line[1] )
    line_to   = ( line[2], line[3] )
    pygame.draw.line( screen, white, line_from, line_to, 3)    

for line in board_lines:
    for rect in board_rects:
        rect = rect[ 0: -1 ] # trim off the colour
        intersection_points = lineRectIntersectionPoints( line, rect )
        for p in intersection_points:
            pygame.draw.circle( screen, blue, p, 10 )  # Draw a circle at the intersection point

#updateing window
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: if i want to add circle on the corners of rectangle too then can i use rect[0] and rect[1] or i have to use this part of the code                                                                                    
 ```  ### Convert the rectangle into 4 lines
    rect_lines = [ ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y ), ( pos_x, pos_y+height, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ),  # top & bottom
                   ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x, pos_y+height ), ( pos_x+width, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ) ] # left & right
```

Comment: @shyckh - Yes, those points define the corners of rectangle.