# How can I write a repeating movement function without using global variables?

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing my first game in Pygame, and I created an enemy creator function in order to call this enemy between the given coordinates. (calling inside while loop)

```
def foot_function(x_1, x_2, y_foot):
    global x
    global rubbish_2
    global rubbish_3
    global rubbish_4
    steps = int((x_2 - x_1) / 3)  # numbers of steps between x_1 and x_2
    if rubbish_3:
        rubbish_2 += 1
    if not rubbish_3:
        rubbish_2 -= 1

    if rubbish_2 >= steps:
        rubbish_3 = not rubbish_3
        rubbish_4 = 'right'

    if rubbish_2 < 0:
        rubbish_3 = not rubbish_3
        rubbish_4 = 'left'

    if rubbish_4 == 'right':
        window.blit(foot_right, (x_1 + 3 * rubbish_2 - x, y_foot))
    if rubbish_4 == 'left':
        window.blit(foot_left, (x_1 + 3 * rubbish_2 - x, y_foot))
    death_function(x_1 + 3 * rubbish_2 + 5, y_foot + 5, 90, 90)
```

The problem is because I am using global variables inside this function; if I try to call this function again, 2 enemies do the same movement although I give them different input.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is really hard to understand your code with so many rubbish variables. It is a good practice to name variables meaningfully. Secondly, You should use Classes, for creating objects. That way you won't need to use global variables and also using classes will make your work easy. Lastly, If you want function to update values without global variables, you can return from the function and store it to the variable you want. If you want more specific help, you should consider renaming rubbish variable to something that is understandable.

Comment: You should use a data structure to group your related data together (in Python, you usually use a `class`) and then add those data to a collection and work with that (Python offers you a e.g. `list`). When using pygame, you can use the `Sprite` and `Group` classes. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988851/running-a-if-statement-only-once-in-pygame/54004065#54004065).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to write a stateful update function without keeping global state. There are two ways I know of to do this somewhat sanely.

### Classes

You basically do exactly what you would do with global variables but in the state stored in the object. This allows you to run two independent `FootClass` objects simultaneously, for instance.

```py
class FootClass():
    def __init__(self, x_1, x_2):
        self.x_1 = x_1
        self.x_2 = x_2

    def move(self, dx_1, dx_2):
        self.x_1 += dx_1
        self.x_2 += dx_2
    ...
```

### Functional

The second way is to have the thing running this keep the state, and then write an update function.

```py
def move_func(x_1, x_2, dx_1, dx_2):
    return (x_1 + dx_1, x_2 + dx_2)

def game():
    init = (1, 2)
    while not_dead():
        init = move_func(*init, 2, 5)
```

This is a strange example because I don't really know much about what you're trying to do specifically, but this is the general idea.